# Selenium: Page logo is replaced, need to verify if the new logo appears

Tags: selenium, test-automation-framework

I have a webpage, where there is an option to upload a new website logo.

When the new logo is uploaded, it has the same element id that of the previous logo.

I have written the automation script using selenium to upload the new image, but I need to verify via automation that the webpage is displaying the new logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot perform image recognition in selenium, following way can be used.

1. Upload image with unique file name (Probably appending the date and time to image file)
2. Verify the after new image name file name in the image tag is what you uploaded.

P.S: For image recognition you can use open source automation tool which is based on image recognition called sikuli (http://www.sikuli.org/). You can integrate this tool with selenium

Comment: Is there any other way in which the image recognition can be done apart from human intervention ?

Comment: Yes, there is a open source automation tool which is based on image recognition called sikuli (http://www.sikuli.org/). You can integrate this tool with selenium

Answer (score 0):

For verifying Look and feel of the application , What Did was integrating an image comparison library to my selenium scripts .Selenium has the capability of taking screenshots , what we need to do is developing a solution which could compare the screen shots taken in current run against previously taken set of screens . In my case I had lot of screen shots to compare , but in your case if Logo is the only thing to be verified , You can use a static web page to do this easily . I have used free image comparison library written in .net as I am working with Selenium C# driver